# Is there a way to ask the user for a password or not with psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Is there an option in psycopg2 (in the `connect()` method) similar to `psql -w` (never issue a password prompt) and `-W` (force psql to prompt for a password before connecting to a database)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`psycopg2` will never prompt for a password - that's a feature of `psql`, not of the underlying `libpq` that both `psql` and `psycopg2` use. There's no equvialent of `-w` / `-W` because there's no password prompt feature to turn on/off.

If you want to prompt for a password you must do it yourself in your code: trap the exception thrown when authentication fails because a password is required, prompt the user for a password, and reconnect using the password. That's what `psql` does anyway, if you take a look at the sources.

Comment: I wanted to know if I had to do it manually or not. Thank you!